# How can I send Skype messages with Cortana on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, skype, cortana

Cortana can send text messages (via phone). Assume a user does not have a phone with Cortana on it.

Instead the user wants to send a simple message (e.g., I will be 10 min late) via Skype. 
Something like

"Hey Cortana, send a Skype message to Violet saying I will be 10 min late."

What is the command and setup to use.

Do I have to have Windows 10's native Skype app installed? (using with same MS account as my Cortana?)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible as of Sep 2017.

Cortana is stupid in many other aspects. (e.g., dismiss the alarm (that is currently "ringing")